# grep on strace only working with stderr to stdout

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe, strace

when i do:

```
sudo strace -p PID 2>&1 | grep -v "recvmsg"
```

grep matches the lines it ought to match, but when i do:

```
sudo strace -p PID|grep -v "recvmsg"
```

It still shows all calls.
Why is that?

Comment: No need to grep. You can select recmsg in this way: `strace -e trace=recvmsg -p PID`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because strace writes all its output to stderr, not stdout.  And a pipe redirects stdout, not stderr.  So you need to redirect stderr of strace to stdout before piping to grep.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using Standard Output for its Standard Output?

Comment: Yes: some debugging tools use stderr because they assume your program may write its own stuff to stdout.  This may make it easier to keep strace's output separate from the output of what you are tracing...or it can just be annoying.  :)